# How to assign a value to a variable which name is in a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a config file which looks like this:

```
$ cat .config
PARAM1 = avalue                 # a comment
PARAM2 = "many values"          # another comment
# PARAM3=blabla
```

I wrote a function to read from it:

```
get_from_config_file()
{
        A=$(grep "$1" ${config_file} | grep -v "^#" | sed s'/^[[:space:]]*//g' | sed s'/#.*$//' | sed s'/^.*=[[:space:]]*//' | sed s'/[[:space:]]*$//' | sed s'/"//g')
        echo "$A"
}
```

Then I can read the parameters from the config file which works fine:

```
PARAM1=$(get_from_config_file "PARAM1")
PARAM2=$(get_from_config_file "PARAM2")
```

But I wanted to make it better (I have many parameters in this config file) so I wanted to be able to grab the value of all my parameters and then assign to variables in a simple for loop -- and here I got in trouble:

```
for name in PARAM1 PARAM2
do
        value=$(get_from_config_file "$name")
        echo $name, $value
        # How to assign here $value to a variable named PARAM1, PARAM2 which is contained in name ?
        # Note that I do not want to use an array for this
        # param[$name]="$value"
done
```

Thanks,

Comment: How about this answer? --> https://askubuntu.com/a/743641 (note: you have to remove whitespace around '=' in the config file.)

Comment: Where does `.config` come from? Trying to parse an arbitrary configuration file in shell, without fully understanding its intended semantics, is generally a bad idea. Use an established configuration file that has a parser for it already.

Comment: This is just a config file with param=value; would you have examples on how to do it better as you advise ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define variables directly using `declare`

```
for name in PARAM1 PARAM2
do
    declare -gx "$name"="$(get_from_config_file "$name")"
    #echo $name, $value
    # How to assign here $value to a variable named PARAM1, PARAM2 which is contained in name ?
    # Note that I do not want to use an array for this
    # param[$name]="$value"
done
echo PARAM1="$PARAM1"
echo PARAM2="$PARAM2"
```

When you run this command, `declare -gx "$name"="$value"`, Bash expands the variables, `name` and `value`, first. Then execute the command, `declare -gx PARAM1=foobar`

```
declare options:
  -g    create global variables when used in a shell function; otherwise
        ignored
  -x    to make NAMEs export
```

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly ! just that -g does not exist for my declare : GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) but it works without so I am good, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

```
for name in PARAM1 PARAM2
do
        value=$(get_from_config_file "$name")
        eval "$name"="$value"
done
```

This should assign the way you want.

Also for `get_from_config_file` how about,

```
awk -v input="$name" -F" = "  '$0 ~ input{split($2, arr, "#"); print arr[1]}' .config
```

Comment: The eval didn't work for me so I used ```declare -gx "$name"="$(get_from_config_file "$name")"```` . For the awk yes, the thing is that I won't be the only user of this and I suspect the future users not to exactly respect the config file format and then complain this is why I removed all these spaces.

Comment: @FredDENIS, good you got your solution. Its a good idea to mark the question as answered. As provided you with the soln.

Answer (score 0):

`read` is the command you are missing.  `while` and `read` can be used together to read variables from a file.  How you process the file to remove the comments is up to you; there are many ways.  In the following example, I used [`sed` to remove the # comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157328/how-can-i-remove-all-comments-from-a-file) and convert the delimiter `=` to a single space.

```sh
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d;s/#.*//;s/[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*/ /' "/.config" \
  | while read -r name value; do
      echo $name $value
    done
```

Comment: `IFS=" = "` doesn't do what you think; it treats any space or `=` as a field separate, not the 3-character string `' = '`.

Comment: @chepner typo, I meant `IFS=' ='`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: why would it be better than grep and sed ? Here I remove the space before and after "=", etc ... as I won't be the only user of this and I anticipate people not really following the config file format :)

Comment: @FredDENIS I updated it so everything is pre-processed in a single `sed` command and then `read` just looks at the results.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the whitespaces around = signs the file can be interpreted as shell script:

```
. .config
```

If you don't want to edit the file:

```
eval "$(cat .config | sed 's/ = /=/')"
```

Comment: Use `.`, not `eval`, when the file is a valid shell script.

Comment: @chepner True, although if the white spaces are there it's not

Comment: Just removing the whitespaces may not be sufficient (or even correct); suppose the file has a line like `foo = this is the value`.

Comment: Edited the first option to use . instead of eval

Comment: Yeah, sed is a better option instead of tr if there are white spaces in the values (edited)

Comment: `foo = what about a = inside a value`?

Comment: Without /g only the first one is replaced

Comment: Are you sure the config file *guarantees* that the first `=` is surrounded by *exactly* one space on either side?

Comment: No but that's what the example showed. Depending on what exactly is the format of the config file the parsing might have to be altered.

Comment: Don't assume the example is exhaustive.